# Issue in overriding config with env variables in dropwizard

Tags: java, environment-variables, dropwizard

MyWebConfiguration.java Have the following code as drop wizard described

```
public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyWebConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    LOG.info("Initializing configuration");
    // Enable variable substitution with environment variables
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
       new SubstitutingSourceProvider(
           bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
             new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)
       )
   );
}
```

dev-services.yaml file have

```
tokenSecret: ${TOKEN_SECRET}
```

but when I run the application and debug to check what value I am getting for tokenSecret, it shows me tokenSecret = "${TOKEN_SECRET}" in debug console.

I tried changing MyWebConfiguration.java as following:-

```
bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
       new SubstitutingSourceProvider(
           bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
             new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(true)// changed false to true
       )
   );
```

But now when I try to run the program, it shows me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" io.dropwizard.configuration.UndefinedEnvironmentVariableException: The environment variable 'TOKEN_SECRET' is not defined; could not substitute the expression '${TOKEN_SECRET}'.
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.EnvironmentVariableLookup.lookup(EnvironmentVariableLookup.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.resolveVariable(StrSubstitutor.java:726)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.substitute(StrSubstitutor.java:649)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.substitute(StrSubstitutor.java:563)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.replace(StrSubstitutor.java:305)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.SubstitutingSourceProvider.open(SubstitutingSourceProvider.java:39)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.YamlConfigurationFactory.build(YamlConfigurationFactory.java:80)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:124)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:72)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
```

Can anyone tell me where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Where do you set the actual env variable. In your class, write a main and do: System.out.println(System.getenv("TOKEN_SECRET")); and see if the output is not null. Are you running in eclipse?

Comment: yes, I am running it in eclipse.
If i run it through terminal, it works.

Comment: Your eclipse environment doesn't know about your env variables. You need to go into your run configuration and set the variables there

Comment: okay thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was in something completely different than what the title and the question suggests - environment variables propagation from the IDE rather than from the system.
Basically it's "why isn't this code working?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment variables are not propagated. There is no automatic propagation from your system to the IDE you were launching DropWizard from.

Secondly, when using `new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)` (non-strict), you need to provide default values, even if they should be empty:

```
tokenSecret: ${TOKEN_SECRET:-}
```

When missing, strict will throw `UndefinedEnvironmentVariableException` and non-strict will use empty string.